# How can I fix the security.oauth20.token.limit.error?

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token, ibm-sbt, ibm-connections

I am using IBM Connections 5.0 as an Identity Provider for my web app.
The code has been working fine, but after a little while (dozens http-requests) the following error occurs

```
[11/28/14 14:50:50:292 CET] 000001f9 OAuth20Endpoi E   security.oauth20.token.limit.error
```

I know this is because I am asking too often for a new accesstoken, but I want to know if there is a way to reset the counter or increase the limit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Documentation for the OAuth provider, you can reference.  http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/connections/4.5.0/doc/accessible/admin/en_us/acc_p4.html

You may want to export

> AdminTask.exportOAuthProps providerName fileName

and see what properties are there, and available for change.  Then you'll want to import

> AdminTask.importOAuthProps providerName fileName

I hope this helps.   If not, I recommend opening a PMR